# Python: find_all in Beautiful soup does not return what is expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, findall

I have an html like this:

```
        <ul class='Whs-nw M-0 items'>
            <li>
                <a href='/news/stocks-hold-slight-gains-amid-140642829.html' class='D-b Fz-s Fw-400' data-ylk='rspns:nav;t3:sub0;elm:hdln;elmt:ct;itc:0;pkgt:15;g:e3b49674-fd8a-3acb-9395-4ac0811af672;ct:1;cpos:2;'>
                <div class='P-0 Whs-n'>
                    <div class='M-0 Pt-2 Ov-h'>


                    <p class='M-0 D-i'>Dow closes down more than 150 as Wal-Mart, Boeing weigh</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
```

I am trying to use `Beautifulsoup` to exctract `/news/stocks-hold-slight-gains-amid-140642829.html` and I am doing it like this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tmp= soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class' : 'Whs-nw M-0 items'})
```

But `tmp` is empty when I look at it.
Am I doing something wrong?

For the reference the page that I am trying to scrape is **[HERE](http://finance.yahoo.com/)**.

Comment: what library are u using for getting content request , selenium httplib etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `tmp= soup.findAll('ul', {'class' : 'Whs-nw M-0 items'})` or `tmp= soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class' : 'Whs-nw M-0 items'})`

Working code-

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://finance.yahoo.com/')
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tmp= soup.findAll('ul', {'class' : 'Whs-nw M-0 items'})
for i in tmp:
    print i.get_text()
```

Comment: I found that your code worked with `findAll` and `find_all`. But hey, it is working! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using `bs4`, when I do it with the old version it fails, but with the new version it works. So, you should be doing:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
tmp= soup.find_all('ul', attrs={'class' : 'Whs-nw M-0 items'})
```

Not `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: I am using bs4, can you extract the part that I mentioned?

Comment: Yes, I converted it to a string and in bs4 it works fine.

Comment: Did you try that? The page may not actually contain the data that you want when you do the web request. It may be loaded by an ajax call.

Comment: Why I thought you were using the old version is that it didn't support the subclasses with spaces like you're doing...

Comment: No I look at page source and it is there so is not loaded by Ajax call.

Comment: Well that doesn't mean it's not loaded by an ajax call. You would have to reload the page with the inspector open, and look at network calls and see if anything came through to verify that in your browser I believe... Rather I suggest verifying that it is contained in your actual urllib request's response text...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`temp = soup.find('ul', attrs={'class': 'Whs-nw M-0 items'}).find('a')['href']`

or you can do this:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`

```
temp = soup.find('a', {'class': 'D-b Fz-s Fw-400'})['href']
```

`print temp`

output:
/news/stocks-hold-slight-gains-amid-140642829.html